# not able to change background using CCLayerColor and initWithColor:cc4(255,255,255,255)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am working on very first tutorial on cocos2d understanding basic concept.I am trying to change background color from default(black) to white.here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface GameScene : CCLayerColor {

    CCSprite *player;
}  
+(id) scene; 
@end
```

and implementation goes here:

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameScene  
+(id) scene  
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];  
    CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];  
    [scene addChild:layer];  
    return scene;  
}  
-(id) init  
{  
    if ((self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)])) {

        self.isAccelerometerEnabled=YES;  
        player= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-72.png"];  
        CGSize screenSize=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];  
        float imageHeight=[player texture].contentSize.height;  
        player.position=CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, imageHeight/2); 
        [self addChild:player z:0 tag:123];  
    } 

    return self;  
} 



-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration  
{
    CGPoint pos=player.position;  
    pos.x+=acceleration.x*10;  
    player.position=pos;  
}
- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCDirectory only takes CCScenes. So most likely the black screen you experience is not a faulty CCColorLayer, but simply the blank stage.

Subclass CCScene as GameScene, then add a CCLayerColor to that with your desired color, as well as your player. Then call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:gameScene]`.

Comment: thanks for the reply,if i try using [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[gameScene node]], and commenting +(id)scene (from both GameScene .h and GameScene .m) every thing works fine as expecting. i am trying to understand why?what's the concept behind this..

Comment: Why what? CCDirector is the world, CCScenes are the chapters of your game, and everything attached to CCScene is the pieces of your game.